# Redirect to another page by width of browser window JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I run my code with xampp and when I access my html file (with Firefox), I am redirected even if my browser has more than 1400 on width.

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
<title>Packet</title>
<script src="my.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Hello, Paul! </h1>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my javascript code on "**my.js**" file:

```
if (screen.width <= 1400) {
    window.location = "mobile";
}
```

I tried to clean the cookies, but doesn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: what does `screen.width` return? console log it instead of the `window.location`

Comment: `screen` - huh, what is it?

Comment: straw, if screen.width is smaller than 1400, autoredirect to mobile folder

Comment: screen is windows of browser

Comment: exactly, try my suggestion in the first comment and see what that returns in the console for various widths, I think as @TrevorClarke suggests, [window.innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window/innerWidth) is what you're after?

Comment: __The `screen.width` property returns the total width of the user's screen, in pixels__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`screen.width` returns the width of your monitor, not the document.

There's `document.width` for the purpose.

```
if (document.width <= 1400) {
    window.location = "mobile";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
window.innerWidth
```

instead of `screen.width`

That should do the trick!

Comment: are you sure your screen is not larger?

Comment: try changing the value to 1